# WCF SOAP have a namespace for the Method Name but not the Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I have the following SOAP request:

```
<your:SendCount>
    <Parameter>
        <Count>12345</Count>
    </Parameter>
</your:SendCount>
```

The method SendCount has a namespace, while the Parameter does not.

I need to create a Service to be able to recieve these types of calls.
So far I have this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "CountBinding", Namespace = "http://yourserver/")]
public interface ICountServer
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "", Name = "SendCount")]
    [return: XmlElementAttribute("return")]
    long SendCount([MessageParameter(Name = "Parameter")] CountClass Parameter);
}
```

So the original request containing your:SendCount fails as the namespaces don't match. How can I add the namespace **(your:)** only to the SendCount Method, but not the other elements?

Tried the above and received:

```
<SendCount>
    <Parameter>
        <Count>12345</Count>
    </Parameter>
</SendCount>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you can use [Message Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors). The operation is performed after the client receives the soap request.

You can follow [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706539/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-to-soap-envelope-in-c-sharp) if it helps you.